# Resize TextView to see strings correctly

Tags: android, xml, layout, textview, size

I have a problem with a TextView. It has some sentences from a DDBB, and It has to load one by one when the user answer the question.

The problem appears when some sentences are too long or with long words, and thas words miss some characters on the screen.

For example, I have this word at the end of the first line of the textview: "affects", and I only see on the screen "affe" because it goes to the end of the screen and it doesn't change the line.

Can anyone solve my problem? I put the XML code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.prodintec.am_motion.QuizActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp">

        <TableRow
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/HeaderTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:text="FOUR OPTIONS QUESTION" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/answer1"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:background="@color/primary"
                android:textColor="@color/accent"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:text="ANSWER 1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/answer2"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:background="@color/primary"
                android:textColor="@color/accent"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:text="ANSWER 2" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/answer3"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:background="@color/primary"
                android:textColor="@color/accent"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:text="ANSWER 3" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/answer4"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:background="@color/primary"
                android:textColor="@color/accent"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:text="ANSWER 4" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/HeaderTextView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="SEE ACRONYM BUTTON FOR MORE INFORMATION" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:paddingStart="10dp">

        <TableRow
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/acronism"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:background="@color/primary"
                android:textColor="@color/accent"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:text="ACRONYM" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/PointsTextView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="POINTS:  "
        android:textAlignment="textEnd" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The textview that has the problem is the one called: "HeaderTextView"

Comment: android:layout_width="368dp" remove this add  android:layout_width="fill_parent"...try this

Comment: it doesn't work. It does the same.

Comment: android:layout_width="match_parent"                        headerTextView.setMinLines(2);

Comment: @JuturuYugandhar with that I have all the string in one sentence only... I soppose that I put the android:layout_width=match_parent" on the "TextView" object.